# Is it viable to write a web-based mobile app with native navigation?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I'm writing a mobile application for android and iOS. I'm quite experienced with Javascript, HTML, and CSS; thus I would like to write the majority of the app with these languages. However, the fundamental navigation between the different "areas" of the app would be done with native navigation—this would be Java on Android and Swift on iOS. Is this a viable approach? Do the app store and marketplace typically accept apps of the kind? What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a website looking like an android app, then using the view WebView. Webviews display the site as it is in the application.
For informations about WebView, go to developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html